# Three.js: Why's my shoe loading upside down and how do I get rid of that crazy metal look?

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

Why's my shoe loading upside down?, how to get it to load the right way up? And how do I get rid of those crazy metallic highlights?

[Here's the working code](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/1/) and 
[here's the json model file](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/1/models/shoe4.json). (I tried to do a plunker, but couldn't get around CORS issue of needing to load an external 6mb json file :( )

Here's my JS:

```
var scene, camera, renderer, geometry, material, cube, group, textureUrl, texture;

init();
render();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 275, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 20;

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera);

    //set background to have transparency - alpha: true
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.getElementById("viewport").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();  
    loader.load("models/shoe4.json", function (obj) {
        scene.add (obj);
    });


  // lights

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
  light.position.set( 300, 300, 300 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
  light.position.set( -300, -300, -300 );
  scene.add( light );


  light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
 scene.add( light );



function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    scene.rotation.y += 0.005;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to disagree with the previous answer...

1. Your model is upside down because the field-of-view of your camera, `camera.fov`, is 275 degrees. A reasonable value is 50 degrees.
2. All your `MeshPhongMaterial`s have a `shininess` of 50. That is a perfectly reasonable value, and fairly low. `material.shininess` can range from 1 to 1000 or more for `MeshPhongMaterial`.
3. The "crazy metal look" is because you have set the *specular reflectance of the material* -- the `material.specular` property -- too high. A reasonable value in your case is:

   `material.specular.setRGB( 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 );`

three.js r.71

Comment: Good find on that FOV ;) A ```shininess``` of 50 is still higher than the default which is 30, one has to play around with these values. I guess I could delete my answer, its not needed anymore?!

Comment: @FalkThiele  1. The default value is arbitrary in this case... 2 . Keep answering, though, it is a great way to learn!

Comment: Thanks much! Where do I alter the `material.specular` property in the JS? I can only find `"specular": 8355711` in the json file. Unfortunately `material.specular.setRGB( 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 );` doesn't seem to be having an effect :(

Comment: Oh, lol. `material` is undefined. Is there a way to change all of them together?

Comment: Traverse the objects inside your load function after they have been loaded: ```obj.traverse(function ( child ) { if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { child.material.specular.setRGB( 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 ); } }```

Answer (score 4):

If your model is upside down in your scene then maybe its just exported on its head. Could be an error with Y-up, best to fix it in your 3d Software. If you want to fix it in code, you can just rotate the geometry by 180 degrees:

```
var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI/2);
obj.geometry.applyMatrix(transformation);
```

Or you can also just rotate your mesh (-group) if you dont want to hassle with the geometry by doing
`obj.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;`

---

The `crazy metal look` is the specular highlight of your `MeshPhongMaterial`. All your materials have a `shininess` of 50, which is higher than usual. Set this value lower and/or darken the `specular` color which is the color of the highlight.

Materials take some time tweaking to look good in three.js, you will have to play around with the values depending on your lighting also.

Comment: Thanks so much, very helpful.

Comment: Or `geometry.rotateZ(180)`?

Comment: Actually i was wrong, it should be `geometry.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2)` (which is 90 degrees). Anyway the mistake is that I was using degrees!